# Designing a method to construct a new dataframe from specific columns of another dataframe without variable input parameters

Tags: python, pandas

My problem: I want to construct a methode which conncects specific columns of a dataframe and by that designs a new datafreame. I don't want to specify at the beginning how many and which columns I want to use. 
My goal is to connect the columns by column, like stacking them next to each other.

At the moment my code looks like this:

Attempt 1:

```
def construct_features(df, *cols):

    features = pd.DataFrame()

    for col in cols:
        features = pd.concat(df[col])

    return features
```

I also tried using a list:

Attempt 2:

```
def construct_features(df, *cols):

    features = []

    for col in cols:
        features.append(df[col], axis=1)

    return pd.DataFrame(features)
```

My function call looks like that:

```
feature_matrix = construct_features(dataframename, 'colname1', 'colname2', 'colname3')
```

The first attempt gives me the following error message:
TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"

The second attempt gives me this error message:
TypeError: append() takes no keyword arguments

For the second attempt I know that the problem is axis=1. But if I leave it out, the output isn't in the desired shape. It gives me a list of size 3 and I actually have no clue what that means.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: it's not really clear, you have an existing dataframe with columns, you want to recreate this by using concat or append ?? I think if you show your sample input and expected output that's much better

Comment: Why iterate over the `cols`, rather just use `df[cols]` to select all desired columns and concat the resulting dataframe onto the other frame?

Comment: I agree with both of the comments above, it's difficult to tell what is actually going on here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly maybe try

```
def construct_features(cols, df):
    if isinstance(cols, list):
        return df[cols].copy()
    elif isinstance(cols, str):
        return df[[cols]].copy()
    else:
        print('Cols is not a list or string')
```

This should take in either a list of cols or single string as well as your dataframe `df` and return a copy a version of the original dataframe under the expectation that the `cols` are in `df.columns`.  Is this what you wanted your function to do ?